# Sort on nested column with aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following query using aggregation framework in Mongoose:

```
Comment.aggregate([{
   $match: {
     isActive: true
   }
 }, {
   $group: {
     _id: {
       year: {
         $year: "$creationDate"
       },
       month: {
         $month: "$creationDate"
       },
       day: {
         $dayOfMonth: "$creationDate"
       }
     },
     comments: {
       $push: {
         comment: "$comment",
         username: "$username",
         creationDate: "$creationDate",
       }
     }
   }
 }, {
   $sort: {
     'comments.creationDate': -1
   }
 }, {
   $limit: 40
 }], function (err, comments) {
   //...
 });
```

Finally, I want to sort the records using `creationDate` inside `comments` array. I've used `comments.creationDate` but it doesn't work!

What is the correct approach to sort items using aggregation framework?

Comment: I don't think you're using the aggregation framework, particularly the `group` part correctly (although I may be wrong). Why are you assigning the `creationDate` value so many times. I also think that syntactically you can't say `$year` or `$month` since `$` can't be on the left side for a variable like that (I think).

Comment: @Trust Here I want to group records on a specific day, month and year. Group-by works perfectly, but sort doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, perhaps try using the `unwind` pipeline before you `sort` to unwind the `comments`. Again I'm not sure if this is exactly what you have to do but just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: @Trust Let me try it, thanks for suggestion btw.

Comment: The $sort looks ok to me, maybe using the $out operator will show some insight on how the documents your $group operator generates look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `$sort` on `creationDate` above the `$group` so that it affects the order the `comments` array is built using `$push`.  As you have it now, you're sorting the overall set of docs, not the array.

```
Comment.aggregate([{
   $match: {
     isActive: true
   }
 }, {
   $sort: {
     creationDate: -1
   }
 }, {
   $group: {
     _id: {
       year: {
         $year: "$creationDate"
       },
       month: {
         $month: "$creationDate"
       },
       day: {
         $dayOfMonth: "$creationDate"
       }
     },
     comments: {
       $push: {
         comment: "$comment",
         username: "$username",
         creationDate: "$creationDate",
       }
     }
   }
 }, {
   $limit: 40
 }], function (err, comments) {
   //...
 });
```